# Determine the closure, interior, and boundary set $\mathbb{Q}$ of all rational numbers as a set of $\mathbb{R}$ with its standard topology.

Tags: general-topology

Determine the closure, interior, and boundary set $\mathbb{Q}$ of all rational numbers as a set of $\mathbb{R}$ with its standard topology.
My answer are the following:
        Boundary set: $\mathbb{R}$
        Closure: $\mathbb{R}$
        Interior: $\emptyset$.
Is my answer correct? thank you.

Comment: If you're asking "am I correct?" then you are. Your question says "I am correct", which isn't a question.

Comment: @ Ethan Bolker. Okey. Thank you so much..